Prove that $ d(p,q)= \sup\{|a_i -b_i| : i\in \mathbb N \cup\{0\}\}$ is a metric on Poly$(\mathbb R)$
Consider the collection Poly $(\mathbb R)$ of polynomial functions from $\mathbb R$ to $\mathbb R$.
Each member of Poly $(\mathbb R)$ can be represented as a sum $\sum_{i=0} ^{\infty} a_i x^i$, where the $a_i$ are real numbers, all except a finite number of which are zero, and the $x^i$ are the power functions $x \to x^i$ .
For each $p,q \in \text{Poly } (\mathbb R)$
with $p= \sum_{i=0} ^{\infty} a_i x^i $ and $q= \sum_{i=0} ^{\infty} b_i x^i$,
Define
$$ d(p,q)= \sup\{|a_i -b_i| : i\in \mathbb N \cup\{0\}\}$$
Prove that $d $ is a metric on Poly$(\mathbb R)$.
I proved that three conditions of metrics. But I have problem with proving that
$\sup\{|a_i -b_i| : i\in \mathbb N \cup\{0\}\}$ has to be a real number.
I tried to find an upper bound for this set $ \{|a_i -b_i| : i\in \mathbb N \cup\{0\}\}$
So by the completeness of $\mathbb R$ we can say that this set has a sup in $\mathbb R $
But I couldn't. I know that for any $a_i $ and $b_i $
$|a_i -b_i| \le |a_i|+| b_i| \le 2\max \{|a_i|,| b_i|\} $
But I can't use that because neither $|a_i|$ nor $| b_i|$ are bounded.
Any help?

Since all but a finite number of $a_i$ are zero, there exists an integer $i_1 \geq 0$ such that $a_i=0$ for all $i \geq i_1$.
Similarly, there exists an integer $i_2 \geq 0$ such that $b_i=0$ for all $i \geq i_2$.
Hence, $|a_i-b_i| = 0$ for all $i \geq \max\{i_1,i_2\}$.
Thus, $\{|a_i-b_i| : i \in \Bbb N \cup \{0\}\}$ is in fact a finite set.

Now I got it. Thank you vey much.
